# Toggle Different Text Based On Clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, typo3

I've done a lot of searching on this subject and found tons of different methods. While some come close, I haven't found what I'm looking for yet.

Basically, I'm working in Typo3 and I'm trying to create a number of links, that when clicked will change text that is displayed in a given area below the links. When a new link is clicked, I want the previous text to be overwritten with the info from the new info link.

An easier way to understand what I am talking about is to think about a picture gallery except instead of displaying a picture, the text changes. Please let me know if I am not being specific enough. Anything helps.

UPDATE:
I'm trying to do something very similar to what you see on this page. Except instead of the div becoming visible on hover, the text displays and stays OnClick until the next selection is made.

Using this code for hover, but need it to be OnClick to display.

```
<script language="Javascript">
<!--
function ShowPicture(id,Source) {
if (Source=="1"){
if (document.layers) document.layers[''+id+''].visibility = "show"
else if (document.all) document.all[''+id+''].style.visibility = "visible"
else if (document.getElementById) document.getElementById(''+id+'').style.visibility = "visible"
}
else
if (Source=="0"){
if (document.layers) document.layers[''+id+''].visibility = "hide"
else if (document.all) document.all[''+id+''].style.visibility = "hidden"
else if (document.getElementById) document.getElementById(''+id+'').style.visibility = "hidden"
}
}
//-->
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#Style {
position:absolute;
left:218px;
top:300px;
visibility:hidden;
border:none 1px #CCC;
padding:5px;

}
</style>

<div id="CC1" style="position:absolute; left:30px; top:472px;"><a href="#" STYLE="TEXT-DECORATION: NONE" onMouseOver="ShowPicture('Style',1)" onMouseOut="ShowPicture('Style',0)"><center><h1 style="color:white; font-size:125%;">Lorum Ipsum<center></a></div>
<div id="Style"><img src="http://www.example.org/fileadmin/template/images/CCSS/TextBox.png"><div style="position: relative;top:-285px;font:12pt;font-weight:bold;color: #0067b2;margin-left: 15px;width:280px">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div></div>
```

---

I managed to get the effect I wanted using this code. Now my only issue is that when the page first loads all divs are displayed until one is clicked. Thoughts?

```
function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
 $('div[name|="newboxes"]').each(function(index) {
      if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
           $(this).show(200);
      }
      else {
           $(this).hide(600);
      }
 });
}
```

Comment: Where will the new text come from? Could you post the code you have.

Comment: Consider using jQuery the .toggle() function makes that quite simple.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick example of how to achieve this. You havent specific where the new text will come from, so I've just used a `data-*` attribute. You can change this to be whatever you need - whether it's another element, AJAX call etc.

```
<p id="message"></p>    
<a href="#" data-text="Message #1" class="link">Show message #1</a><br>
<a href="#" data-text="Message #2" class="link">Show message #2</a><br>
<a href="#" data-text="Message #3" class="link">Show message #3</a><br>
<a href="#" data-text="Message #4" class="link">Show message #4</a><br>
<a href="#" data-text="Message #5" class="link">Show message #5</a><br>
```

```javascript
$(".link").click(function() {
   $("#message").text($(this).data("text"));
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Uw6W9/)

Comment: I'm trying to do something very similar to what you see on this page. Except instead of the <div> becoming visible on hover, the text displays and stays OnClick until the next selection is made.

[link] (http://www.greatbooks.org/index.php?id=2068)

Answer (score 0):

It's solved by the [rgaccordion](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/rgaccordion) extension in your example.

If you are using TemplaVoila, you can easily create an [FCE which accommodates your markup](http://wiki.typo3.org/TemplaVoila/FCE)

Comment: Unfortunately the accordion doesn't do what I said I was looking for. I need a div to appear in a specific area solely based on what link you click, not a drop down list where multiple things can be shown at once. If you can make RGAaccordion do this, I don't know how, but I'll look into it. Thanks for the feedback though.

Comment: That is ALL divs need to appear in the SAME given area when the links that are located in different areas are clicked